# Is gravitational lensing "additive" in a line of sight?

Tags: general-relativity, optics, gravitational-lensing, galaxy-cluster, star-cluster

As usually depicted, gravitational lensing implies, at least, three objects: a distant source, an observer, and a "massive enough" object in the middle, where enough is the mass needed to make an observation and strongly suggest we're measuring the consequences of the effect.

[image]

If, instead of one "massive enough" object, we would have two, or, more generally, any mass distribution, the images would get distorted consecutively as they travel towards (or reach) the observer. So my question is simple: would these distorsions be additive, meaning that we could treat the problem as different lenses and do, e.g., Fourier Optics to compute? ([Related article](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2019/04/aa24881-14.pdf))

As context, I was just wondering how do you know, when you measure gravitational lensing, that in between you have only one object that, to first order, is distorting the source's image, and not two, three, or N, and how come that stars or galaxy clusters' precision astrometry data is not all "biased" because of GR effects when this is not considered.

Comment: Good points.  You might enjoy reading about the Euclid mission.  https://www.euclid-ec.org/public/core-science/